# Is it a java best practice?

Tags: java

I am reading the source code of [XposedBridge](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge).

I am confused when I am reading the following codes

```
do {
    label65: {
        try {
            ((XC_MethodHook)callbacksSnapshot[beforeIdx]).beforeHookedMethod(param);
        } catch (Throwable var18) {
            log(var18);
            param.setResult((Object)null);
            param.returnEarly = false;
            break label65;
        }

        if(param.returnEarly) {
            ++beforeIdx;
            break;
        }
    }

} while(beforeIdx < callbacksLength);
```

As far as I know, the code `break label65` means that it will break out of the `while` area, but it is the same with the `label165` area. What is the function of  the label `lable165`? Is it a best practice about java that I don't know.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, please revise it

Comment: I don't think label is necessary here...

Comment: Sounds to me like another opinion based question..

Comment: That code could be written cleaner *without* the use of the label. So is it a 'best practice'? Absolutely *not*. Labels do have some justification cases when used in *nested lops*.

Comment: This looks like output from a decompiler, and not source code that somebody wrote by hand. Note that decompilers do not recover the exact original source code from a compiled class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not considered good practice.

It appears that this code was produced by a decompiler, and I suspect that the label and `break` were actually a `continue` statement, which *is* perfectly fine if you need to exit a loop early and go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad practice in Java and is often thought to be similar to GOTO statements that are notorious for creating spaghetti code.

If you are needing to use labeled break statements in Java it usually means that there is a better way of structuring your logic/loops to avoid them. I personally find them confusing, especially when they are abused.

However, they ARE different to GOTO statements in that you can only jump to a specific location. And they can be useful to break out of a nested loop completely on a specific condition.

Comment: `GOTO` statements are notorious, yes, but they have an undeservedly bad rep.  You can write crummy code without a single `goto`, and you can write perfectly fine code with them.  Spelling it "break" or "continue" is much in vogue, but doesn't change its fundamental nature.  I agree that this particular code falls on the crummy side, though.

Comment: That's true @JohnBollinger, but with GOTO statements it is very easy to use them incorrectly and abuse them. The code in the original question is very confusing because of the labeled block so it is an example of bad code. However, if you use a labeled loop to break out of an outer loop from the nested inner loop, this can be a lot easier to read/understand than the extra logic it would take to do that without them.

Answer (score 0):

Its like GOTO statement and functioning as recusive calling. Its not a very good practice though.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, the code break label65 means that it will break out of the while area, but it is the same with the label165 area.

Actually, it will break to the end of the labelled statement.  If you look at the brackets carefully, that means it breaks to immediately before the

```
    ++beforeIdx;
```

at the end of the loop.

> What is the function of the label lable165?

See above.

> Is it a best practice about java that I don't know.

It is not best practice.  The way that the label has been used here makes the code hard to understand, and that is BAD practice.

---

In fact, if this is hand-written code, then I suspect it doesn't do what the author thinks it does.  If you look at the stuff with the `returnEarly` flag, it is being set in the exception handler and then tested in the statement after the `try ... catch`.  But the handler also breaks to the label which skips over the `if` statement!

That *might* be intentional, but if it is then it is a horribly obscure / obfuscated way of coding that logic.

---

@cryslis wrote:

> Note my answer. I think it's a decompiled continue.

I also suspected that it was decompiled code.  The strange local names (`label65` and `var18`) are another clue.

However, you said that you found the source code a Github repo.  The two things are not mutually exclusive ... but if someone is decompiling code and uploading it to Github, that is pretty shonky, and possibly illegal.  I didn't want to point the finger without clear evidence.  And I can't find the source code with `label65` and `var18` in the repo.

Certainly it not "best practice" to decompile code and upload it to Github.

And if you are getting bytecodes and trying to understand them by decompiling, then that is not "best practice" either.

Comment: Note my answer. I think it's a decompiled `continue`.

Comment: Look closely: the label adorns a block that surrounds the `try` / `catch` and `if` statements, so breaking from that statement puts you at the bottom of the loop.  A `continue` statement would therefore serve the same purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - In which case, this is an obscure way of "writing" a `continue` .... and very bad practice.

Comment: Exactly. It's poor practice, but I suspect that the bytecode is the same and that a decompiler got confused.